# array indexing method a tricky case

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
int buff[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10};
char c = (buff+1)[5];
printf("%d\n",c);//output is 9
return 0;
}
```

Can someone explain it clearly how this is happening and why

Comment: I think it must be 9.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Recall:**

In C the square braces `[ ]` are  implicitly `*( ... )`.

---

What is going on in the snippet of code you provided is *not obvious* pointer arithmetic. This line:

```
char c = (buff+1)[5];
```

... is equivalent to the following (by the C standard):

```
char c = *( ( buff + 1 ) + 5 );
```

... which points to the 7th element in the array (6th position) and dereferences it. It should output 9, not 19.

**Remark:**

Following the note about square braces, it's important to see that the following is equivalent.

```
arr[ n ] <=> n[ arr ]
```

... where `arr` is an array and `n` is a numerical value. A more complicated example:

```
' '[ "]; i < 0; i++; while ( 1 ); do something awesome (y)." ];
```

... of entirely valid pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Krishnasundar, added one other important thing to remark for future run ins with pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Well, if two additions count as "very clever" then I must be a real genius for understanding multiplication...

Comment: @H2CO3, it's clever in the fact that the question was asked (so it's not obvious). I'll fix my wording to be demoralizing.

Answer (score 6):

```
{1,    2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  9,  10};
 |     |
 buff  buff+1 = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10} (say buff_1)
                                |
 buff_1[5]    =                 9
```